# iOS getting date string from RSS Feed

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, ios6, nsattributedstring

I have an XML parser that uses RaptureXML to grab each item and display it within a table cell.  I already can get the title and description, but I can't seem to work out how to get the date.

Here's what I have so far for the date:

```
NSString* dateString;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.pubDate];


[articleAbstract appendAttributedString:
 [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: dateString]
 ];
```

I keep getting this showing up in the debugger:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's the full code:

**RSSItem.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RSSItem : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL* link;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSAttributedString* cellMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* pubDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* dateString;

@end
```

**RSSItem.m**

```
#import "RSSItem.h"
#import "GTMNSString+HTML.h"

@implementation RSSItem

-(NSAttributedString*)cellMessage
```

{
        if (_cellMessage!=nil) return _cellMessage;

```
NSDictionary* boldStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]};
NSDictionary* normalStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0]};

NSMutableAttributedString* articleAbstract = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.title];

[articleAbstract setAttributes:boldStyle
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, self.title.length)];


[articleAbstract appendAttributedString:
 [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]
 ];

// Parse for date

NSString* dateString;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.pubDate];


[articleAbstract appendAttributedString:
 [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: dateString]
 ];

[articleAbstract appendAttributedString:
 [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]
 ];

int startIndex = [articleAbstract length];

NSString* description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [self.description substringToIndex:100]];
description = [description gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];

[articleAbstract appendAttributedString:
 [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: description]
 ];

[articleAbstract setAttributes:normalStyle
                         range:NSMakeRange(startIndex, articleAbstract.length - startIndex)];

_cellMessage = articleAbstract;
return _cellMessage;

}

@end
```

**EDIT: Here is my RSS Loader**

```
#import "RSSItem.h"

#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

@implementation RSSLoader

-(void)fetchRssWithURL:(NSURL*)url complete:(RSSLoaderCompleteBlock)c
{
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    //work in the background
    RXMLElement *rss = [RXMLElement elementFromURL: url];
    RXMLElement* title = [[rss child:@"channel"] child:@"title"];        
    RXMLElement* pubDate = [[rss child:@"channel"] child:@"pubDate"];

    NSString *usableDate = [pubDate];       

    NSArray* items = [[rss child:@"channel"] children:@"item"];

    NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:items.count];

    //more code
    for (RXMLElement *e in items) {

        //iterate over the articles
        RSSItem* item = [[RSSItem alloc] init];
        item.title = [[e child:@"title"] text];            
        item.pubDate = usableDate
        item.description = [[e child:@"description"] text];
        item.link = [NSURL URLWithString: [[e child:@"link"] text]];
        [result addObject: item];
    }

    c([title text], result);
});

}
```

Can someone please help me parse my date correctly?

Comment: stringFromDate returns nil. add an NSLog(@"%@ => %@", self.pubDate, dateString); to see what is null ....

Comment: @Daij-Djan i tried that and it returns null. How do I actually get the date?

Comment: You need to set the `pubDate` property. It will be `nil` until you give it a value. None of the code you posted shows how you attempt (or not) to set the property.

Comment: @rmaddy I added my RSS Loader to show how this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you added to your question, the problem has to do with how you set the `pubDate` property. You defined the property to be an `NSDate` but you set an `NSString` value to the property in your RSS loader code.

You need to convert the string obtained from the XML file to an NSDate or change your `pubDate` property from `NSDate` to `NSString`. If you do the latter then your earlier code needs to be updated to reflect this change.

The decision is really dependent on what you need to do with the date.

Comment: I want to get the date and format it to the format: Sunday, November 25, 2012.  Is it possible to do all that in the string format?

Comment: You'll need to replace `item.pubDate = [[e child:@"pubDate"] text];` with code that uses another `NSDateFormatter` to convert the string found in the XML file to an `NSDate` object. Then you can use your existing code in `cellMessage` to convert the `pubDate` to the desired date string.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like stringFromDate returns nil.

If you're meaning the YYYY is year, it is not correct, you should use yyyy instead. But I don't think that problem in the date format. Maybe pubDate is nil?

Comment: should be a comment though .. it isnt an answer :P

Answer (score 1):

you have to retain the date object.Whenever you will assign date object to another string or date formatter just give like [date retain].It works