# Remove Time format from Date received from RSS Feed iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I am getting date from RSS feed. which is in NSString format.

This is how my Feed class

```
@interface Feed : NSObject
{
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *link;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *desc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pubDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageUrl;
```

Here `pubDate` is `NSString`

When I NSlong this, it gives me correct output.

like

```
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 00:00:00 GMT
```

Now I want to remove this `00:00:00 GMT`

I tried a lot and searched a lot, but after conversion it gives me `(null)` value

I tried this link as well
[iOS getting date string from RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556884/ios-getting-date-string-from-rss-feed)

Here is my code for date conversion,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:feed.pubDate];
    NSLog(@"final %@", stringDate);
```

And output for final is

```
final (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may help you...

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[self ConvertDate_Format:feed.pubDate]);
 //Pass Your date

-(NSString *)ConvertDate_Format:(NSString*)inputStirng
{
    NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dformat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy,hh:mm:ss"];
    [dformat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    return [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:[dformat dateFromString:inputStirng]];
}
```

Comment: Inside the Function is 'inputStirng' has value ?

Comment: I tried the same now, that you have edited. Thanks. now its working after editing.